# Error if nothing found when replacing a string (selection replace, find replace)

Tags: excel, vba

This is the error I receive when running my macro. I thought I already addressed when the find function doesn't find what I'm searching for by implementing an if statement. Somehow it's still not working...

**How can I skip the find/replace statement if the value I'm searching for doesn't exist in my record?**

[image]

My VBA Code:

```
Columns("D:D").Select
Set Example1 = Selection.Find(what:="Example One", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If Not Example1 Is Nothing Then
Selection.Replace what:="Example One", Replacement:= _
    "Test One A", lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
    , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
    FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End If

Set Example2 = Selection.Find(what:="Example Two ", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If Not Example2 Is Nothing Then
Selection.Replace what:="Example Two ", Replacement:= _
    "Test One B", lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:= _
    xlReplaceFormula2
End If
```

Comment: Does the replacement value potentially create an invalid formula?

Comment: On which line does the error occur ???

Comment: Btw - `FormulaVersion` is a new parameter for `Range.Replace`, and unsurprisingly, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) hasn't been updated :-)

Comment: It occurs on the first Selection.Replace (Example One). @BigBen What does that mean? Also No, it shouldn't create an invalid formula as it's worked before. It's just now that I've used it on a different file it cannot find the value and thus gives the error

Comment: Actually yeah, FormulaVersion seemed to have caused the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2` seemed to be the culprit to this issue. Once I removed it, code work as needed. Also, `On Error Resume Next` was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

just a quick thing: `on error resume next`. this jumps tu the next line when an error raise. not the best choice but in this code it can be helpful

Comment: Thanks, I guess this will have to be a temporary fix until I find a more permanent one.

Comment: Maybe you looked for nothing, where false is the answer. I think I remember that find gives back true or false.

Comment: That's why I included the if statement to address if find returns false than just skip it (since Example1 would return nothing if that string was not found).